# Paragraph translation in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I translated a site using django i18n, I have no problems for menus, little paragraph, etc..
The thing I dont understand is for translating big paragraph. On my site, the admin can write some news by administration page, but he wants them in differents languages.

I can imagine some methods to do that :

- one field per langage, but it will be difficult to manage with severals languages (for example news table has title and content, we will have 4 fields ? title_en title_fr content_en content_fr ?
- update the .po file for each new news ?
- the real solution ?

What is the best solution for that ?

Thanks ! (sorry for my english)

Comment: This is already part of Django: Please read this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/  Then please read http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Concepts.  Then please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for, but it sounds like you have a model called `News` that you want to be multilingual aware.

[There is a page](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ModelInterNationalization) on the Django wiki that covers some differing approaches to the problem of storing multilingual content in models, including the one you describe of having a field for each language in the model. It also links to a number of different Django apps that attempt to solve the problem.

Based on my experience, I'd take a look at [django-datatrans](http://github.com/citylive/django-datatrans) which seems to me to be best-of-breed both in it's approach (one object per language) and feature set.